# Linking the TGUI library with cmake

Tags: c++, user-interface, cmake, sfml, static-linking

sorry for bothering you, but I got a problem with including libraries with Cmake. I wanted to include the tgui library in my sfml project, but I don't know how to do it. I somewhat found out how to include the sfml library, but I couldn't find how to include the tgui library, and everything I tried and searched for failed.

At their website there's described how to use it, but not how to implement it.

Here's the cmake file of my project (up to the sfml linking):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)    
project(AntWorld)    

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")    

set(SOURCE_FILES "main.cpp")    
add_executable(AntWorld ${SOURCE_FILES})    

# include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*")    


# Define sources and executable    

set(EXECUTABLE_NAME "Run_AntWorld")    

add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} main.cpp)    



# Detect and add SFML    
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})    
find_package(SFML 2 REQUIRED system window graphics network audio)    
if(SFML_FOUND)    
    include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})    
    target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SFML_LIBRARIES})    

endif()
```

well, that's the working code until now.

I tried to adapt the way it is described at

[www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/How_to_create_a_ProjectConfig.cmake_file](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/How_to_create_a_ProjectConfig.cmake_file) .

This was the most promising post, but well, somehow I couldn't find out what they actually tried to explain since they described paths and or files not included in their hierarchy at all (or I just didn't get it, but the errors where there either way).

Everything else I tried failed just as spectacular as this one.

Ah, for the Library I tried to link:

https://github.com/texus/TGUI

You can download it on their website (https://tgui.eu/) too, I tried it with version 0.6.7 (the not-precompiled version) since I'm on Linux with Clion. And if that's the issue, what can I do to get it working?

Either way, every help is appreciated, I hope I don't bother you doing something important.

Answer (score 1):

The way to link to TGUI is almost identical as how you link to SFML.

In your cmake_modules folder you probably already have a FindSFML.cmake file. You have to copy FindTGUI.cmake there as well (it can be found in TGUI_Path/cmake/Modules).

In order to find the TGUI library you would just call find_package

```
find_package(TGUI 0.6 REQUIRED).
```

Linking would look like this

```
target_link_libraries(target ${TGUI_LIBRARY} ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
```

Full example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(TestProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})

find_package(SFML 2 REQUIRED system window graphics network audio)    
find_package(TGUI 0.6 REQUIRED)

if(NOT SFML_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find SFML")
endif()

if(NOT TGUI_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find TGUI")
endif()

add_executable(TestProject main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(TestProject ${TGUI_LIBRARY} ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: well, thanks, at least now it returns only one error, one you probably can help me with: "Error: Could NOT find TGUI" (from the FindTGUI.cmake). I included it in a folder of my project, where should I put it to get found? I looked in it and tried on my own a bit but It didn't work ...

Comment: @blueBurningCoder When building tgui (following [the linux tutorial](https://tgui.eu/tutorials/v06/linux/), you are supposed to run "sudo make install" at the end which would install tgui so that it can be found automatically. If you don't want to or can't install tgui (e.g. no root access), then you can always set the TGUI_ROOT variable in cmake to the tgui directory (which must include "lib" and "include" subfolders). But in that case you might also need "include_directories(TGUI_Path/include)" in your cmake script. But installing TGUI properly makes using it easier.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't find this one ... either way when I tried it it stopped at 38% with the following Error:

/home/blueburningcoder/Downloads/TGUI/src/TGUI/EditBox.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void tgui::EditBox::mouseMoved(float, float)’:
/home/blueburningcoder/Downloads/TGUI/src/TGUI/EditBox.cpp:1172:69: error: ‘class sf::String’ has no member named ‘substring’ (and more like this)
.  
.  
.  
make[2]: *** [src/TGUI/CMakeFiles/tgui.dir/EditBox.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [src/TGUI/CMakeFiles/tgui.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: Trying it again, it failed even earlier, at 17 % with the same error message:    
make[2]: *** [src/TGUI/CMakeFiles/tgui.dir/EditBox.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** [src/TGUI/CMakeFiles/tgui.dir/TextBox.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/TGUI/CMakeFiles/tgui.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: You need to use SFML 2.2 in order to use TGUI 0.6.7. You could always pick an [older release](https://github.com/texus/TGUI/releases) if you really need an older sfml version. The releases before v0.6.7 will work with SFML 2.1. But if you plan to deploy your program on windows or mac then I suggest you use v0.6.7. For linux only minor things where changed after v0.6.6 though.

Comment: Thanks, working now. Then tried to use the namespace tgui, but my IDE couldn't resolve it - why? I included the TGUI.hpp with `#include <TGUI/TGUI.hpp>` now, at least that's working.

Comment: @blueBurningCoder I don't understand what you mean with your IDE not being able to resolve it. But instead of keep chatting in the comments could you perhaps make an account and a topic on the [TGUI forum](https://forum.tgui.eu/) and explain it there in more detail?